# Jackson - Can the DEDUCTION type take the datatype into account?

Tags: java, jackson

I have the following JSON, where my property can either be a String, a Number or a reference to a variable:

```
[
  {
    "prop": "string-value"
  },
  {
    "prop": 5
  },
  {
    "prop": {
      "$variable": "var1"
    }
  }
]
```

I want to deserialize this into 3 subclasses, for this I am trying to use DEDUCTION:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.DEDUCTION)
@JsonSubTypes({ @Type(MultitypeString.class), @Type(MultitypeVariable.class), @Type(MultitypeNumber.class) })
public abstract class Multitype {
}

public class MultitypeString extends Multitype {
    public String value;

    public MultitypeString(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class MultitypeNumber extends Multitype {
    public Number value;

    public MultitypeNumber(Number value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class MultitypeVariable extends Multitype {
    @JsonIdentityReference
    @JsonProperty("$variable")
    public Variable variable;
}
```

For the variable reference this works fine but for string and numeric values I get the following error:

```
Subtypes MultitypeNumber and MultitypeString have the same signature and cannot be uniquely deduced
```

Which is weird since the signatures do vary, one is a String constructor and one is a Number constructor.
Is there a way I can have the DEDUCER take the datatype into account?
If not, is there another way to get what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look at documentation for the `DEDUCTION` field:

> Means that no serialized typing-property is used. **Types are deduced**
> **based on the fields available**. Deduction is **limited** to the names of
> fields (**not their values or, consequently, any nested descendants**).
> Exceptions will be thrown if not enough unique information is present
> to select a single subtype. If deduction is being used annotation
> properties visible, property and include are ignored.

It can recognise a type only by a unique field name. Field types are not taken into account.

You can extend default implementation, [AsDeductionTypeDeserializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsontype/impl/AsDeductionTypeDeserializer.html). Take a look at [buildFingerprints](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/bbf650f8db05f6aa7e9f39d2685fb620ba7c5707/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsontype/impl/AsDeductionTypeDeserializer.java#L62) method, you need to implement another way how to build `fingerprints` map.

Also, you need to implement proper type handling in [deserializeTypedFromScalar](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsontype/impl/AsArrayTypeDeserializer.html#deserializeTypedFromScalar-com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser-com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext-) method.

Comment: Do you have an example of a custom AsDeductionTypeDeserializer?

Comment: @JaB, I do not have it. If you have a problem with it try to create a new question and point to this one.